# Execute function in stateless component after timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a loading spinner in a stateless functional component that I'm using while I check for props.

I'd like to use `setTimeout` to have the loading spinner display for 5 seconds and then change the content if props are still not available, but this code doesn't seem to work:

```
function LoadingIndicator() {
  let content = <span>Loading Spinner Here</span>;
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('6 second delay');
    content = <span>Page could not be loaded.</span>;
  }, 6000);
  return (
    <div>
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I believe this doesn't work because nothing tells react to re-render this component, but I'd prefer not to upgrade to a container if possible.

Comment: This does not appear to be a react class; can you show how you are using react in your example plz?

Comment: it's not a class - it's a stateless functional component. This component is simply displayed while API calls are in progress.

Comment: content = <span>Page could not be loaded.</span>; has no quotes, is this something to do with React, a typo, or the problem?

Comment: I believe this is valid JSX - if I remove the `setTimeout`, the first `let content` renders as expected.

Comment: I believe you should change your **stateless** component to **stateful** one, as you want to change the state of your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the timer to the parent. Have the timer change a state value and in its render, pass that state value as a prop to your LoadingIndicator.

Comment: I was hoping to achieve this within the component so it could be simply dropped in, but I hadn't considered simply passing the timeout changes in a prop - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make your component stateful, so you can change its state easily.

```js
class SpinnerComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { tooLong: false };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    var thiz = this;
    
    setTimeout(function () {
      thiz.setState({ tooLong: true });
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  render() {
    let content = 'Spinner...';
    
    if (this.state.tooLong) {
      content = 'It takes too much time...';
    }
    return (
      <div>{content}</div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <SpinnerComponent />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but since the parent is already a container I prefer the solution of simply passing in a prop to my stateless component - thanks.